# How can I grab info from a database using Django's tags?

Tags: python, django, tags

I've put content into the Django's database, which relates to class FullArticle in my `models.py` file, I've read the documentation about {{tags}}, but I'm confused about what to include in my .py files/ how to grab that data dynamically and put it into my html file.

This is a screenshot of what the project looks like now: http://imgur.com/sWiuQ8J

Optimally, instead of hard coding the title of each individual article using my `<h1>` tag it would be `<h1>{{title}}</h1>` and grab the data related to `title = models.CharField(max_length=150)`

Let me know if this is the right approach to doing this and what I need to include in my .py files.

Answer (score 0):

just fetch the related article and pass that into template...

```
dev artical_view(request):
    templateVar = {}
    templateVar['artical_object'] = FullArticle.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'article.html', templateVar)
```

And in your html,

```
<div>
{% for article in artical_object %}
 <h1>{{ article.title }}</h1>
 <p> {{ article.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: For the first code snippet, which .py file am I putting that in?

Comment: I tried putting the first part of the snippet in my views.py and then the second part in my html and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: the above code is definitely will work .. come again what part is troubles